# allow third parties to change elements

Tags: php, jquery

Take the [following plugin](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php)- What would be the best way to actually allow third parties to make changes to the image,description and link elements - like allow each individual their own block ,as in membership or advertsing site?

Comment: Create an admin console for that...? Store data in the database and get it out for display...? Sorry, this question is too broad. What difficulty do you have in creating such a system?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that animation is handled by the plugin.  The image and text elements are just regular elements like you would have on any page.

You would have to store (for each customer), their settings for their "box".

- Path to the image
- Title text
- Description text

After that it's up to you how to let your users change the values.  You could have some sort of administrator console that would require your customers to log in with a password... You could allow users to upload files to a certain folder via FTP and you could extract the data from there... You could even go 100% manual and require them to email you for any change.

It all depends on how you want to allow them to do this.

Comment: Great. The admin console sounds like it. Is this done specifically through my server or can external software be used? And lastly, how would I id each 'block' so that each individual is directed to theirs?
 Thanks for your response.